# vstest@2 dump file created in Azure Devops but test shows up as passing

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, nunit, vstest

We have a test that looks like it has an access violation, creates a dump file, but does not show up as a failing run.  Is it possible that continueOnError causes this?

Here is our YAML:

```
  - ${{each testItem in parameters.testsToRun}}:

    - task: VSTest@2
      timeoutInMinutes: ${{parameters.testtimeout}}
      displayName: 'Run ${{testItem.testAssemblyName}}'
      inputs:
        testAssemblyVer2: ${{testItem.testAssemblyName}}
        searchFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\bin\$(BuildPlatform)\$(BuildConfiguration)'
        runSettingsFile: RunSettings.runsettings
        runTestsInIsolation: false
        testRunTitle: ${{testItem.testAssemblyName}}
        platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
        diagnosticsEnabled: True
        testFiltercriteria : ${{testItem.testFiltercriteria}}
      continueOnError: ${{parameters.continueonError}}
```

**This portion looks odd to me:**

```
2021-11-23T07:55:48.8985329Z [07:55:48] Exception: C0000005.ACCESS_VIOLATION
2021-11-23T07:55:48.8992920Z [07:55:48] Dump 1 initiated: d:\work\_temp\TestResults\testhost_5848_50cdff5df075468ba19b2d52ed4c95de.dmp
2021-11-23T07:55:50.3692657Z [07:55:50] Dump 1 complete: 44 MB written in 1.5 seconds
2021-11-23T07:55:50.6340543Z [07:55:50] Dump count reached.
2021-11-23T08:04:13.5354083Z Passed   FailureCreationTest_FromInteropWR(True,False,evHighestPriorityEvent,evMatchOnActivityCode)
2021-11-23T08:12:19.5551269Z Passed   FailureCreationTest_FromInteropWR(True,False,evHighestPriorityEvent,evMatchOnDamageCode)
2021-11-23T08:15:56.9689927Z Passed   FailureCreationTest_FromInteropWR(True,False,evHighestPriorityEvent,evMatchOnObjectPart)
2021-11-23T08:16:06.6469765Z NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution complete
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9543510Z Results File: d:\work\_temp\TestResults\burlington.build_APMTestGrpC004_2021-11-23_08_04_13.trx
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9564456Z Total tests: 3. Passed: 3. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9565080Z Test Run Successful.
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9573198Z Test execution time: 21.3407 Minutes
```

**Here is the full log output:**

```
2021-11-23T07:54:40.6099393Z ##[section]Starting: Run TestInterop.dll
2021-11-23T07:54:40.6250682Z ==============================================================================
2021-11-23T07:54:40.6251388Z Task         : Visual Studio Test
2021-11-23T07:54:40.6252180Z Description  : Run unit and functional tests (Selenium, Appium, Coded UI test, etc.) using the Visual Studio Test (VsTest) runner. Test frameworks that have a Visual Studio test adapter such as MsTest, xUnit, NUnit, Chutzpah (for JavaScript tests using QUnit, Mocha and Jasmine), etc. can be run. Tests can be distributed on multiple agents using this task (version 2).
2021-11-23T07:54:40.6252949Z Version      : 2.170.1
2021-11-23T07:54:40.6253202Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2021-11-23T07:54:40.6253534Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/vstest
2021-11-23T07:54:40.6253912Z ==============================================================================
2021-11-23T07:54:41.3746606Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2021-11-23T07:54:41.4374555Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2021-11-23T07:54:41.5602073Z Running tests using vstest.console.exe runner.
2021-11-23T07:54:41.5602500Z ======================================================
2021-11-23T07:54:41.5603533Z Test selector : Test assemblies
2021-11-23T07:54:41.5604127Z Test filter criteria : Category=FCreate_IntWR_Gr4
2021-11-23T07:54:41.5604727Z Search folder : d:\work\1\s\bin\x64\Release
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6104366Z Action when minimum tests threshold not met : donothing
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6104814Z Minimum tests expected to be run: 0
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6105664Z VisualStudio version selected for test execution : latest
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6107535Z Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation with version [16.0,17.0).
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6110915Z Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio build tools installation with version [16.0,17.0).
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6116309Z Attempting to find vstest.console from a visual studio installation with version [15.0,16.0).
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6165252Z Run settings file : d:\work\1\s\RunSettings.runsettings
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6170119Z Run in parallel : false
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6171756Z Run in isolation : false
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6172327Z Path to custom adapters : null
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6175889Z Other console options : null
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6177760Z Code coverage enabled : false
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6182342Z Diagnostics enabled : true
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6219502Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6260031Z Run the tests locally using vstest.console.exe
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6260466Z ========================================================
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6276829Z Source filter: TestInterop.dll
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6905574Z SystemVssConnection exists true
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6907723Z [command]d:\work\_tasks\VSTest_ef087383-ee5e-42c7-9a53-ab56c98420f9\2.170.1\Modules\DTAExecutionHost.exe --inputFile d:\work\_temp\input_9d81d491-4c32-11ec-96eb-e70621ca237f.json
2021-11-23T07:54:41.6908395Z ======================================================
2021-11-23T07:54:41.7293916Z ##########################################################################
2021-11-23T07:54:41.7294361Z DtaExecutionHost version 18.170.30112.1.
2021-11-23T07:54:42.0280519Z Starting TestExecution Model...
2021-11-23T07:54:43.7783840Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2021-11-23T07:54:43.8262546Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2021-11-23T07:54:43.8420804Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9105933Z Result Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9106505Z Run Attachments will be stored in LogStore
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9265713Z Provided settings file:
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9276591Z <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9277051Z <RunSettings>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9277352Z    <RunConfiguration>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9277705Z       <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9278242Z           <!-- TestSessionTimeout was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9280930Z           <!-- Specify timeout in milliseconds. A valid value should be greater than 0 -->
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9281542Z           <!-- Setting to 90 minutes = 5400000.  We may need to bump up, but hopefully not. -->
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9282193Z           <!-- MA - Setting to 8 hours = 28800000. Temporarily, so that we can see how long TestInterop actually takes. -->
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9282789Z       <TestSessionTimeout>28800000</TestSessionTimeout>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9283168Z    </RunConfiguration>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9283460Z </RunSettings>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9500982Z Updated Run Settings:
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9501451Z <RunSettings>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9502256Z   <RunConfiguration>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9502768Z     <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9503304Z     <!-- TestSessionTimeout was introduced in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.5 -->
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9504077Z     <!-- Specify timeout in milliseconds. A valid value should be greater than 0 -->
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9504729Z     <!-- Setting to 90 minutes = 5400000.  We may need to bump up, but hopefully not. -->
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9505466Z     <!-- MA - Setting to 8 hours = 28800000. Temporarily, so that we can see how long TestInterop actually takes. -->
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9506106Z     <TestSessionTimeout>28800000</TestSessionTimeout>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9506573Z     <BatchSize>1000</BatchSize>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9507069Z     <ResultsDirectory>d:\work\_temp\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9507555Z   </RunConfiguration>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9507923Z   <DataCollectionRunSettings>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9508305Z     <DataCollectors>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9508732Z       <DataCollector friendlyName="blame" enabled="True">
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9509167Z         <Configuration>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9509676Z           <ResultsDirectory>d:\work\_temp\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9510462Z           <CollectDump />
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9510744Z           <CollectDump />
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9511008Z         </Configuration>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9511266Z       </DataCollector>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9511531Z     </DataCollectors>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9511794Z   </DataCollectionRunSettings>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9512056Z   <LoggerRunSettings>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9512310Z     <Loggers>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9512596Z       <Logger friendlyName="blame" enabled="True" />
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9512901Z     </Loggers>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9513139Z   </LoggerRunSettings>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9513378Z </RunSettings>
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9608175Z **************** Starting test execution *********************
2021-11-23T07:54:43.9776182Z [command]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\..\..\..\Extensions\TestPlatform\vstest.console.exe "@d:\work\_temp\fba00gklt0t.tmp"
2021-11-23T07:54:44.0633762Z Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 15.9.1
2021-11-23T07:54:44.0634425Z Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
2021-11-23T07:54:44.0670949Z vstest.console.exe "d:\work\1\s\bin\x64\Release\TestInterop.dll"
2021-11-23T07:54:44.0671891Z /TestCaseFilter:"Category=FCreate_IntWR_Gr4"
2021-11-23T07:54:44.0672533Z /Settings:"d:\work\_temp\4zbnq34ozfz.tmp.runsettings"
2021-11-23T07:54:44.0673069Z /Logger:"trx"
2021-11-23T07:54:44.0673617Z /TestAdapterPath:"d:\work\1\s\bin\x64\Release"
2021-11-23T07:54:44.3926909Z Starting test execution, please wait...
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4907538Z ProcDump v9.0 - Sysinternals process dump utility
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4908108Z Copyright (C) 2009-2017 Mark Russinovich and Andrew Richards
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4908490Z Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4908802Z Process:               testhost.exe (5848)
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4909313Z Process image:         C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\Extensions\TestPlatform\testhost.exe
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4910554Z CPU threshold:         n/a
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4910857Z Performance counter:   n/a
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4911141Z Commit threshold:      n/a
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4911423Z Threshold seconds:     n/a
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4911729Z Hung window check:     Disabled
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4912029Z Log debug strings:     Disabled
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4912368Z Exception monitor:     First Chance+Unhandled
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4912694Z Exception filter:      [Includes]
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4913003Z                        *STACK_OVERFLOW*
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4913329Z                        *ACCESS_VIOLATION*
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4913629Z                        [Excludes]
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4913936Z Terminate monitor:     Enabled
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4914230Z Cloning type:          Disabled
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4914516Z Concurrent limit:      n/a
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4914809Z Avoid outage:          n/a
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4915090Z Number of dumps:       1
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4915432Z Dump folder:           d:\work\_temp\TestResults\
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4915824Z Dump filename/mask:    testhost_5848_50cdff5df075468ba19b2d52ed4c95de
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4916178Z Queue to WER:          Disabled
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4916490Z Kill after dump:       Disabled
2021-11-23T07:54:46.4916832Z Press Ctrl-C to end monitoring without terminating the process.
2021-11-23T07:54:47.2528605Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.2530442Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:47.2531489Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.4753990Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.4754743Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:47.4755832Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.5256237Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.5257096Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:47.5257463Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.5257828Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:47.5258175Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.5258519Z [07:54:47] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:47.6589478Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.6590022Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:47.6593298Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.6717482Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.6718051Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:47.6721097Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.6798562Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.6799849Z [07:54:47] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:47.7399449Z [07:54:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:47.7400068Z [07:54:47] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:48.0966524Z NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution started
2021-11-23T07:54:48.1064774Z Running all tests in d:\work\1\s\bin\x64\Release\TestInterop.dll
2021-11-23T07:54:49.5129753Z    NUnit3TestExecutor converted 1074 of 1074 NUnit test cases
2021-11-23T07:54:50.1119198Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:50.1119744Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:50.1121785Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:50.1130011Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:50.1134008Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:50.1134497Z [07:54:50] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:50.4637358Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:50.4637915Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:50.4638296Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:50.4641356Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:50.4643139Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:50.4645611Z [07:54:50] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:50.7954029Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:50.7955314Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:50.7955783Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:50.7958928Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:54:50.7959867Z [07:54:50] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:54:50.7962999Z [07:54:50] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:53.4543086Z [07:54:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:53.4594513Z [07:54:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:53.4595038Z [07:54:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:53.4595355Z [07:54:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:53.4596313Z [07:54:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:54:53.4596686Z [07:54:53] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:55:37.0340750Z [07:55:37] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:55:37.0345103Z [07:55:37] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:55:37.3357465Z [07:55:37] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:55:37.3358267Z [07:55:37] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:55:39.6792005Z [07:55:39] Exception: E0000001
2021-11-23T07:55:39.6792545Z [07:55:39] Exception: E0000001
2021-11-23T07:55:39.6792848Z [07:55:39] Exception: E0000001
2021-11-23T07:55:39.6793165Z [07:55:39] Exception: E0000001
2021-11-23T07:55:39.6818099Z [07:55:39] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:55:47.8258523Z [07:55:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEETypeLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:55:47.8259443Z [07:55:47] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:55:47.8260086Z [07:55:47] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEETypeLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:55:48.1551209Z [07:55:48] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:55:48.1552020Z [07:55:48] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:55:48.1552687Z [07:55:48] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:55:48.1553091Z [07:55:48] Exception: E06D7363.msc
2021-11-23T07:55:48.1553439Z [07:55:48] Exception: E06D7363.PEAVEEFileLoadException@@
2021-11-23T07:55:48.1557691Z [07:55:48] Exception: E0434352.CLR
2021-11-23T07:55:48.8985329Z [07:55:48] Exception: C0000005.ACCESS_VIOLATION
2021-11-23T07:55:48.8992920Z [07:55:48] Dump 1 initiated: d:\work\_temp\TestResults\testhost_5848_50cdff5df075468ba19b2d52ed4c95de.dmp
2021-11-23T07:55:50.3692657Z [07:55:50] Dump 1 complete: 44 MB written in 1.5 seconds
2021-11-23T07:55:50.6340543Z [07:55:50] Dump count reached.
2021-11-23T08:04:13.5354083Z Passed   FailureCreationTest_FromInteropWR(True,False,evHighestPriorityEvent,evMatchOnActivityCode)
2021-11-23T08:12:19.5551269Z Passed   FailureCreationTest_FromInteropWR(True,False,evHighestPriorityEvent,evMatchOnDamageCode)
2021-11-23T08:15:56.9689927Z Passed   FailureCreationTest_FromInteropWR(True,False,evHighestPriorityEvent,evMatchOnObjectPart)
2021-11-23T08:16:06.6469765Z NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution complete
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9543510Z Results File: d:\work\_temp\TestResults\burlington.build_APMTestGrpC004_2021-11-23_08_04_13.trx
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9564456Z Total tests: 3. Passed: 3. Failed: 0. Skipped: 0.
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9565080Z Test Run Successful.
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9573198Z Test execution time: 21.3407 Minutes
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9796440Z Vstest.console.exe exited with code 0.
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9797609Z **************** Completed test execution *********************
2021-11-23T08:16:06.9883419Z Test results files: d:\work\_temp\TestResults\burlington.build_APMTestGrpC004_2021-11-23_08_04_13.trx
2021-11-23T08:16:07.3273835Z Created test run: 20611278
2021-11-23T08:16:07.3276400Z Publishing test results: 3
2021-11-23T08:16:07.4465675Z Publishing test results to test run '20611278'.
2021-11-23T08:16:07.4499218Z TestResults To Publish 3, Test run id:20611278
2021-11-23T08:16:07.4588579Z Test results publishing 3, remaining: 0. Test run id: 20611278
2021-11-23T08:16:07.7613266Z Published test results: 3
2021-11-23T08:16:07.7622419Z Publishing Attachments: 1
2021-11-23T08:16:08.8157630Z Completed TestExecution Model...
2021-11-23T08:16:08.8453410Z ##[section]Finishing: Run TestInterop.dll
```

Comment: Perhaps? The real purpose of `continueOnError` is to allow other stages to run even on "failure". An access violation would crash the test executable, but presumably not the agent which spawned the task. Can you provide anything from the log output?

Comment: @WaitingForGuacamole - I've included full log output and also the section that I thought looked strange.  Access Violation -> dump file created -> Test Run successful

We are using vstest and nunit.

Comment: what happens if SysInternals isn't hooked in there? I'm wondering if it's tampering with the application state after the exception gets dumped?

Comment: Thanks, that is a good idea to try :)